# Spring AOP : How to fix this bug

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, aopalliance

I am practising AOP and facing error in simple AOP example.It seems to be Jar version related issue.
I have included all the necessary JAR's CGLib-2.1,aspectjrt-1.6.0,aspectj-1.6.9,aopalliance-1.0.jar

Here is the code :

**

- Beans.xml

**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

       <aop:config>
          <aop:aspect id="log" ref="logging">
             <aop:pointcut id="selectAll" 
             expression="execution(* com.tutorialspoint.*.*(..))"/>
             <aop:before pointcut-ref="selectAll" method="beforeAdvice"/>
             <aop:after pointcut-ref="selectAll" method="afterAdvice"/>
             <aop:after-returning pointcut-ref="selectAll" 
                                  returning="retVal"
                                  method="afterReturningAdvice"/>
             <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="selectAll" 
                                 throwing="ex"
                                 method="AfterThrowingAdvice"/>
          </aop:aspect>
       </aop:config>

       <!-- Definition for student bean -->
       <bean id="student" class="com.tutorialpoint.Student">
          <property name="name"  value="Zara" />
          <property name="age"  value="11"/>      
       </bean>

       <!-- Definition for logging aspect -->
       <bean id="logging" class="com.tutorialpoint.Logging"/> 


</beans>
```

**

- Logging.java

**

```
package com.tutorialpoint;

public class Logging {

   /** 
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * before a selected method execution.
    */
   public void beforeAdvice(){
      System.out.println("Going to setup student profile.");
   }

   /** 
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * after a selected method execution.
    */
   public void afterAdvice(){
      System.out.println("Student profile has been setup.");
   }

   /** 
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * when any method returns.
    */
   public void afterReturningAdvice(Object retVal){
      System.out.println("Returning:" + retVal.toString() );
   }

   /**
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * if there is an exception raised.
    */
   public void AfterThrowingAdvice(IllegalArgumentException ex){
      System.out.println("There has been an exception: " );   
   }

}
```

Main.java

```
package com.tutorialpoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      Student student = (Student) context.getBean("student");

      student.getName();
      student.getAge();

      student.printThrowException();
      System.out.println("helloee");
   }
}
```

Student.java

```
package com.tutorialpoint;

public class Student {
   private Integer age;
   private String name;

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public Integer getAge() {
      System.out.println("Age : " + age );
      return age;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      System.out.println("Name : " + name );
      return name;
   }

   public void printThrowException(){
       System.out.println("Exception raised");
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
}
```

ConsoleOutput

```
Jul 16, 2014 8:44:36 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@63c12fb0: startup date [Wed Jul 16 20:44:36 BST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 16, 2014 8:44:36 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Jul 16, 2014 8:44:36 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6d4b1c02: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#2,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#3,selectAll,student,logging]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 16, 2014 8:44:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6d4b1c02: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#2,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#3,selectAll,student,logging]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#2': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tutorialpoint.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:72)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.bindArgumentsByName(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:420)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.calculateArgumentBindings(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:375)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.getPointcut(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.buildSafePointcut(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor.<init>(AspectJPointcutAdvisor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Your expression has `tutorialspoint` and your package name is `tutorialpoint`. Does fixing that help?

Comment: Thanks Dave,That was a mistake but there is no change in the errorstack.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is crashing when inspecting the class for some parameter names (either `retVal` or `ex`). This information is only available in Java .class files when you compile with debug info enabled (the `-g` option for `javac`). Can you check that you are compiling with debug info enabled?

From the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params):

> **Determining argument names**
>
> The parameter binding in advice invocations relies on matching names used in pointcut expressions to declared parameter names in (advice and pointcut) method signatures. Parameter names are not available through Java reflection, so Spring AOP uses the following strategies to determine parameter names:
>
> - If the parameter names have been specified by the user explicitly, then the specified parameter names are used: both the advice and the pointcut annotations have an optional "argNames" attribute which can be used to specify the argument names of the annotated method - these argument names are available at runtime...
> - If the first parameter is of the `JoinPoint`, `ProceedingJoinPoint`, or `JoinPoint.StaticPart` type, you may leave out the name of the parameter from the value of the "argNames" attribute...
> - Using the 'argNames' attribute is a little clumsy, so if the 'argNames' attribute has not been specified, then Spring AOP will look at the debug information for the class and try to determine the parameter names from the local variable table. This information will be present as long as the classes have been compiled with debug information ( `-g:vars` at a minimum)...
> - If the code has been compiled without the necessary debug information, then Spring AOP will attempt to deduce the pairing of binding variables to parameters (for example, if only one variable is bound in the pointcut expression, and the advice method only takes one parameter, the pairing is obvious!). If the binding of variables is ambiguous given the available information, then an `AmbiguousBindingException` will be thrown.
> - If all of the above strategies fail then an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

Comment: There is a problem with the both after-returning,after-throwing.

Comment: Nothing concrete I have got from JAVAC -g option.